# What is the difference of setcookie() and $_SESSION with session.use_only_cookies?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

We can send some cookies to visitor's browser by `setcookie()`. When defining a value with `$_SESSION['value']`, if using `session.use_only_cookies`, the session will be only stored on the visitor's browsers. What is the difference of these two cases?

**EDIT:** Obviously, they are basically different. I just meant the difference in their application. We can set a value on the client-side, which can be retrieved any time (before expiration of course) with $_COOKIE or $_SESSION equally; e.g. to identify a returning visitor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cookie is stored on the client-side(i.e. "within" the client/browser).
_SESSION is serialized and then stored *on the server*. This data is associated with a session id. E.g. when using the default filesystem session handler the filename reflects the session id. The client (or your script) has to provide that session id in subsequent requests so that php's session management can/will load the session data again. One mechanis for this is to use cookies. `session.use_only_cookies=On` lets php's session mechanism look only for session ids in cookies.

Comment: When we set session.use_only_cookies, session will be stored on the client-side too. This is indeed my question.

Comment: No, only the session id is transmited as a cookie; not the session data itself.

Comment: An interesting point (for me at least). Then, you mean, we only store the session ID on the client-side, and when we run $_SESSION, we read session ID from the visitor's browser and based on the ID we read the corresponding value of session from server?

Comment: @Ali use_only_cookies only affects the sessionid not the session data. i you et this to tue PHP will only use session ids stored in cookies to identify the user. The session data is always stored on the server. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-only-cookies

Answer (score 6):

No, when you set `session.use_only_cookies`, the data from the session are not stored client-side. This settings only affects the way the session ID is transmitted between the client and the server.

Basically there are 2 ways of transmitting this session ID :

- Cookie based
- URL based (with a GET variable like PHPSESSID=...)

When using the setting `session.use_only_cookies`, it prevents the use of the URL to transmit the session ID, only the cookie can be used.

Answer (score 5):

These are completely different things:

1. `setcookie()` sets a cookie in the browser, but this normally isn't the session cookie. The session cookie you create with `session_start()`.
2. `$_SESSION[]` sets/gets a value to/from the session on server side.
3. `session.use_only_cookies` will make sure, that the session id is sent only with a cookie, and not for example in the url.